# php,how to export databse with multiple tables into single excel file with multiple sheets?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpmyadmin

How can i export few selected tables into single excel file with each sheet each table?

Below is my current code.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test1");

if(isset($_POST["download"]))  
 {  

      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=windows-1257');  
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TEST.csv');  
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
      fputcsv($output, array( 'ID', 'Name','type'));  
      $query = "SELECT * from table1";  
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {  
           fputcsv($output, $row);  
      }  
      fclose($output);  
 }
```

Comment: PHPExcel and PHPSpreadSheets are two good library available for creating excel sheets in PHP....Try with one of these....

Comment: @josephthomas i will do research about  PHPExcel and PHPSpreadSheets~thanks ya